# Kernels permanently consume 100% CPU

Tags: kernel, kernel-startup

I have a problem with Mathematica kernels consuming 100% CPU, even when they seemingly idle: I start Mathematica (version 10.1.0 for Linux x86, 64 bit on Linux 2.6.32, server with 4 cores, 16 GB RAM). A process viewer such as "top", however, reports 100% CPU load on the (two) kernels, even before I have issued the first command. The command prompt works fine and is responsive and fast as always, but the kernels remain permanently at 100%, even hours after startup. The same happens on all additional kernels after running ParallelTable[] or such. Once I quit the frontend, the kernel processes terminate as they should.

I have tried renaming the .Mathematica/Kernel/init.m file and also the Applications/ folder to rule out any faulty initialization on my side. Besides that, have not modified any system folders or files.

top reports a stable memory consumption of VIRT=1051m and RES=71m or similar both for either kernel, so it doesn't look like the Linux kernel is swapping (the server is was idling when I ran the last test, anyway).

It looks like the kernels are constantly trying to do something in parallel to their regular (and fully functional) operation that hangs.

Comment: Try deleting the `~/.Mathematica/Paclets` directory.

Comment: I don't have access to a Linux installation, but out of curiosity, do you have access to another similar process viewer, to see if the problem is actual load, or in the load viewing and reporting instead?

Comment: I checked the processor load using top and htop on my linux 3.16 amd-64 machine, running Mathematica 10.1.0.0 . Neither of the two process viewers shows any load after I launched two kernels.

Comment: Is this on an empty notebook?

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20889763#20889763) when using remote kernel on a linux cluster,  but I end up avoiding 10.1 and 10.2 and never solved it.

Comment: @ilian: I renamed the Paclets directory and restarted Mathematica, but the problem remains

Comment: @MarcoB: ps shows the same CPU load as top:

Comment: @MarcoB: ps shows the same CPU load as top: `ps -eo pid,tid,class,rtprio,ni,pri,psr,pcpu,stat,wchan:14,comm` shows e.g. the process `23830 23830 TS       -   0  19   0 62.8 Rl   -              WolframKernel` under the headline `  PID   TID CLS RTPRIO  NI PRI PSR %CPU STAT WCHAN          COMMAND`, hence 62.8% CPU load (4-core server with three active processes; so below 100% CPU seems to indicate that the Wolfram kernels are using a lot of system calls)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Empty or not does not matter. In fact, no notebook at all still has the kernels running hot.

Comment: OK. I asked this be cause sometimes you can have two Manipulates open that are accessing each others variables creating a lot of cpu activity too.

Comment: I just found out that the command line version (math) does not show this problem, so it must be somehow connected to the graphical frontend invoking the kernels

Comment: A few more possible things to try: (1) rename/move `~/.Mathematica/FrontEnd` (2) delete everything in `/tmp/MathLink` (3) attach `strace` to the running kernel process(es) which may yield some clues about what they're doing.

Comment: @ilian: I already tried (1) without success. (2) Deleting the content of `/tmp/MathLink` didn't help. (3) Here's the output of strace applied to one of the two kernels (this output repeats all the time): `Process 15098 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0x2012250, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
futex(0x2011454, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 129090003, {1443002365, 461474000}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

Answer (score 5):

OK, issue solved. The problem is apparently caused by a bug in the Linux kernel related to the insertion of a leap second and is only apparent when queried from Java. A solution is given here (requires super user permissions, but no reboot or even restart of Mathematica):
[Java leap second bug](http://blog.wpkg.org/2012/07/01/java-leap-second-bug-30-june-1-july-2012-fix/)

Comment: Glad it's solved (+1). Was it the strace that pointed in this direction or something else? I'd include this [link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/6/30/122) in the answer, since Java is most likely not relevant (it is not used by the *Mathematica* kernel on startup)

Comment: @ilian: Yes, I googled the strace result and found a post that described the same situation, unrelated to Mathematica. Thanks for the hint. It may be worth adding a check to Linux versions of the Wolfram Kernel to check for this leap second problem?